# How to install Android platform components offline?

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded Android SDK components from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.

Now my question is how to install these components? I am using Eclipse and the AVD plugin for Eclipse is installed.

Comment: Already asked question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you downloaded the components already, you also need to download the "core" sdk from the [android dev site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

extract that to your desired location, then extract the "platform tools" to the platforms directory in the "core", extract the "sdk tools" to the "tools" directory in the "core".

your android sdk directory should look something like this:

- android-sdk-windows

  - tools

    - lib
    - adb.exe
    - emulator.exe
    - ddms.bat
  - platforms

    - android-8

      - tools

        - aapt.exe
    - android-7

      - tools

        - aapt.exe
  - SDK Setup.exe

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Now i am going to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend downloading the components through SDK Manager. If you're having problems doing so, turn 'https' off in the settings and also configure the proxy details if the machine is behind a proxy.

If you still need to download the SDK packages offline, 
Open SDK manager and note down the URL printed in the logs.

It will be something like this,

```
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
```

Open this URL (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml) in the browser and look for "". Jump to the version you want to download and make a note of the appropriate ZIP file you want for your machine. 
Download the ZIP file by appending the name to "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/".

E.g., If you want to download ICS 4.0.3, the ZIP file name is android-15_r01.zip and the URL would be https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-15_r01.zip.

Done!
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't download components directly from that URL.

Instead you should install the SDK components with the [Android SDK and AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html#InstallingComponents) as shown on the Android Developers site.

Comment: Yes you are right but the problem is that my internet connection creates problems. Every time i try to install with AVD it crashes. thats why i want to install these components offline.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android Offline]

I found the answer to this question I think the folder where you should paste the Android zip file is in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\temp
```