# Android Development Environment Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I wanna setup Android Development Environment in Linux. I have done it in Windows before but wanna set it up in Linux. Is there any guide on how i can do it ?

Downloaded Eclipse, Java JDK, ADT, SDK for linux

the SDK is around 25mb only. Looks like it doesnt have the platform files. From where can i download the platform files for 2.2 and 2.3.

I dont have internet on the linux machine.

Comment: IME this process will go much quicker if you have internet access directly on the machine you are installing software on, as the packaging software knows where to go to get the files it needs from the internet.

Comment: @Roflcoptr we have set up a new office and decided to go with Linux. We are waiting for the internet connection. So i was wondering if u can get a copy of the stuff we need i can download and transfer it to it to get going :)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. download and install the JDK
2. download and unzip the android SDK (from developer.andriod.com)
3. export the path to the android sdk (in ~/bash.rc append the line)

   `export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/the/sdk/tools/folder`
4. Download and install eclipse
5. Download the eclipse Plugin
6. Start eclipse
7. Click Help -> Software Updates
8. Click Availble Software
9. Add Site
10. Enter the path to the plugin
11. select the plugin and install

---

That should do it...
Look here
http://www.softwarepassion.com/setting-up-android-development-platform-on-ubuntu-linux-904/
and here
http://fyi.oreilly.com/2009/02/setting-up-your-android-develo.html
for more info

Comment: Harsha wants to do it *without* internet connection.

Comment: Then he downloads them on an other computer and transfer them to the target computer

Comment: Sort of. Like the link @Aleadam posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install