# Unable to download SDK components from android.com

Tags: android, sdk, installation

Running Windows XP, 32 bit.

I had no problem downloading the installer and android-sdk_r10-windows.zip, but when running the installer, it gets stuck opening 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository.xml
When I try browsing to that URL, I get a 404.

I've read some of the other answers suggested, but most either direct me to the sdk download (already done) or mention some obscure command line approach that doesn't seem relevant to a Windows installation.

Thanks for any help!

Dave

Answer (score 2):

First thing to try is to click on the Settings tab and turn on the option to Force https sources to be fetched using http. Then try to refresh the packages.

If that doesn't help are you behind a corporate proxy? If so make sure your proxy server and port are correct in the Settings tab.

If that doesn't work try http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5944#c7 .

And if that doesn't work try [Download the Android SDK components for offline install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install) .

Comment: Settings tab of what? My browser? Installer is running from Windows, not launched from the browser (Firefox.) Yes, I am behind a proxy and firewall; probably the culprit, as usual! I'll try an off-line install tomorrow, after downloading to flash drive tonight. Thanks!

Comment: OK, the off-line access looks good from home. Being a new user/developer, I have what may be a dumb question:  I want to build applications for a device I have, a Curtis LT8025 tablet. It's running Android 2.1, I believe. Do I need to install the 2.1 level SDK, or can I develop with the latest version SDK, for a 2.1 platform?

Comment: Either one. Just make sure minSdkVersion is set correctly in your manifest.