# How to import an android image to the SDK?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.3

I have a very dramatic situation here. I need the android sdk and I'm from a country that google has restricted our access to the android developer website.
I have some how managed to get the android installer and the 2.3.3 version of android in a zip file separately.
What I want to know is how to import this zip file to the sdk so that I can create an AVD?

Comment: See [Android: Download the Android SDK components for offline install](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2766713/566344)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the sdk and copy your image to

> YOUR_PATH\Android\android-sdk\platforms

copy it into the folder with the version code

Comment: I have the file name `android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip`. What is the proper version code?

Answer (score -1):

You can extract zip file to sdk/system-images/android-(api)/default/here

Ex: sdk/system-images/android-24/default/x86_64

Which x86_64 is the folder of extracted zip file