# android offline

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Download the Android SDK components for offline install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install)

I want to learn to develop Android apps, but I can't complete the files I need because I live in Syria and all Android Developers URLs are blocked ("need proxy" which we can't use).

I downloaded ***Eclipse*** and installed the ***ADT Plugin*** and ***SDK Installer*** from a torrent, but I still need **platforms, add_ons, and tools**.

Is there any place where I can download it and install it offline?

This [link](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml) is not working with or without **s**.

Comment: I wish you the greatest amount of luck possible in getting this to work!

Comment: Some other resources:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install

Answer (score 0):

hopefully you can see this page:

http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html

Comment: That just redirects him back to the site he can't access.

Comment: even the direct download links?  damn.  Thought those were past the XML map he was trying to access.

Comment: yes i can't reach the server http://dl-ssl.google.com This product is not available in your country & the proxy or vpn is not available in my country

Comment: if you need such question, the simple solution is to ask somebody to download these for you, and zip it, then send to you via another web site. I share the development environment with whole team via this way.