# How to revert Android SDK Tools to an earlier revision?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Is it possible to revert Android SDK Tools to an earlier revision (for example from r17 to r16 or r15)?

Comment: I think it's not possible. Are there any good reasons to do that?

Comment: because i have some problem with the build of my projects, which actually worked until the update. i've also looked for fixed, but still no solution found and it seem like that the simpliest way to get the builds work again is to revert back the Android SDK Tools revision (at least until in a newer revision it works properly)...

Comment: around switch to rev 17 I believe the libraries changed. You then had to put the libraries in a libs folder to get them deployed properly. Just in case you don't want to stay on r16 forever :-). More information on changes per revision: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html

Comment: @AlexanderKulyakhtin Google sometimes makes breaking changes to its SDK and you need earlier tools , for example, SDK TOOLs update 21 breaks the game engine cocos build system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the older tools, and delete the new ones and unpack the old ones and your done. Is nothing more to it than that.
The tools can be downloaded from the "android" program in the tools directory of you current sdk.

```
android-sdk-linux-17/tools$ ./android
```

Comment: `sh.exe": ./android: No such file or directory`
This is what I get when I run that command from the tools folder.

Comment: Are you sure your standing in the tools directory? 
What does "ls -la" and "pwd" output when you are standing in that directory?

Answer (score 2):

@erbsman  this is not possible to download old version of sdk tool from **Android** too. because it uses an xml file(check logs on **ANDROID TOOL**) to get location of all zip files. so you have to do some kind of hack for that. check out following link for hack

[Download the Android SDK components for offline install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install/9403527#9403527)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having has to do with a change the Android team made to how lib jars are referenced.

Does this solve the problem? http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17