# Android compatibility library (Android support) install problems

Tags: android

I am trying to install the Android Support package (previously known as the Android Compatibility Library, I think) using the SDK Manager, but it keeps (silently) failing to install.

According the the documentation, it should install to my /extras/ directory, but after what looks to be a successful download and installation from the SDK, the directory is empty. There are no errors in the SDK Manager log, and the module says that it is installed in the list of "extra" packages......but it is not!

Has anyone else had any experience of this?

I'm using Wnidows Vista + Eclipse.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: You should accept an answer to close the question. Click the check mark to accept an answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - couldn't figure out why the SDK Manager won't install it, but I did find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install) on StackOverflow that explains how to manually download packages from the Google repository (this is explained in an external blog [here](http://qdevarena.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html))

This means that I can at least download the .zip file and install it manually!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the SDK as admin from the location you had installed.

Comment: Yes - I did end up doing that eventually and it seemed to work. I think there is also an issue with the Eclipse IDE in windows holding onto directories and files and therefore stopping them being deleted/moved during the SDK installation process. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but u wont face these types of issues if you run your eclipse itself as admin. Its a firewall feature of windows to block any outside program to make changes in its heart(OS installed directory).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just not use eclipse at all and add the .jar to your build path manually.

1. Create a directory called "libs" in your project explorer.
2. Drag and drop the support package file (.jar) into your new "libs" directory.
3. Right click the .jar file and click "add to build path".

And there you have it :)

Comment: but I don't have the .jar file - that's the problem! The Android SDK  Manager wont download it!