# Can't find SDK Components installation links?

Tags: android, sdk

I want to do an [SDK Components Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install). But this [XML File](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml) doesn't contain any SDK components download links any more.
That's the content

```
<!--
license blah blah
</sdk:license>
<!-- PLATFORM-TOOLS ........................ -->
<sdk:platform-tool>
<!--
Generated at Sun Jun 24 13:59:38 2012 from git_jb-release @ 391408
-->
<sdk:revision>12</sdk:revision>
<sdk:archives>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="windows">
<sdk:size>11125959</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">74eae05569474ce4fb695f78470e5eedd7495a55</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>platform-tools_r12-windows.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="linux">
<sdk:size>10950326</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">0c3bd46c177f4f5e0c3663965d49bb143f95f071</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>platform-tools_r12-linux.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="macosx">
<sdk:size>11314066</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">76efeb1ed4bc934e9532ad80891c31c1adb51bb8</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>platform-tools_r12-macosx.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
</sdk:archives>
</sdk:platform-tool>
<!-- TOOLS ........................ -->
<sdk:tool>
<!--
Generated at Sun Jun 24 13:52:53 2012 from git_tools_r20 @ 391819
-->
<sdk:revision>20</sdk:revision>
<sdk:min-platform-tools-rev>12</sdk:min-platform-tools-rev>
<sdk:archives>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="windows">
<sdk:size>90245472</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">f958e6b7b6f79e33e0b0c3b8e34888465fd79cfa</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>tools_r20-windows.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="linux">
<sdk:size>82698183</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">6f668f956e30bdf5ab7bb761d5641b04eb4bda84</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>tools_r20-linux.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="macosx">
<sdk:size>58181018</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">0296fa1591d081be2fa05492eaeb9c7a3123a62a</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>tools_r20-macosx.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
</sdk:archives>
</sdk:tool>
</sdk:sdk-repository>
```

Could anyone upload an alternate link or the old XML File. I strongly need the API level 16 Emulator image to get OGL ES 2.0 on it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml)'s the link since a later SDK Tools Version. Admins, [FIX_ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install)