# I can't add new/update Android SDK Manager stuff

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

[image: Screen dump]

I can't add new/update Android SDK Manager stuff. I am trying from a residence in China so no work proxy. Fine to access through a browser as you can see in the background. I tried ticking http instead of https, same effect. I tried running as administrator, same. Tried turning off firewall for 1 min to test, same. No other suggestions shown online so last resort is this.

The Android platforms you see installed in the graphic where manually downloaded and place in the appropriate folders to get them to work, but I can't find items that don't have manual download alternatives. Was fine till I upgraded to SDK tools rev. 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer finally from another post. When I updated Eclipse, I updated from Java version 6 to 7. By returning to version 6 everything works, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2):

Me too in China, since I have one account vps on USA, I make one ssh tunnel proxy, then update sdk with 'tsocks android update sdk', it works, and sometimes it still hang on for no reason, then I find a offline installation way '[Download the Android SDK components for offline install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install)' , wish this would help you.
Maybe this only work on linux OS style, since you are working on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I am also living in China, and I got problems too thanks to the "Great" firewall, like many other websites, sometimes it was working, sometimes not.

What I do is using temporary a VPN to update my SDK when needed. I use this one, in case you need it (a free one): http://www.websitevpn.com/.