# Failed updating SDK packages

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Since it's a blocked site here, sdk manager can't reach **dl.google.com/android**, so I use a proxy.
But using a proxy make the internet speed not stable at all, which is very necessary for SDK manager to update and modify packages, so it always failed doing that.

So, I had downloaded packages from the same link it tries to download from, via download manager like **IDM**,

and here is my problem:

How I can tell SDK manager that here is you packages that you need to download, take it locally not over the internet?

Comment: try copying the downloaded file to your Android SDK `temp/` folder.

Comment: I have tried that, not working

Comment: Use a VPN instead. Try HotSpot Shield.

Comment: Same thing bro, didn't work :(

Comment: I have figured that to let sdk manager see the package in the temp folder, it need the .inf file according to that package beside it, but I didn't know where I can get that .inf file!

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack which I used a long time ago.

1. In the Android Studio find `Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK Update Sites`.
2. Click the **+** icon

*Path 1-*

3. Instead of the url put your folder path
   Warning: This mostly doesn't work

*Path 2-*

3. Install XAMPP
4. Write this in an XML. For customizing XML you can take help from here [for add-on SDK](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml) and here for [essential SDK](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml)

*Note: This snippet is for Add-On SDK*

```
  <addon:sdk-addon>
     <remotePackage obsolete="false" path="add-ons;addon">
      <type-details xsi:type="addon:addonDetailsType">
        <api-level>3</api-level>
        <codename/>
        <vendor>
          <id>google</id>
          <display>Google Inc.</display>
        </vendor>
       <tag>
          <id>google_apis</id>
          <display>Google APIs</display>
        </tag>
        <libraries>
          <library localJarPath="maps.jar" name="com.google.android.maps">
            <description>****Put*fully*qualified*name*here****</description>
          </library>
        </libraries>
      </type-details>
      <revision>
        <major>3</major>
      </revision>
      <display-name>Google APIs</display-name>
      <uses-license ref="android-sdk-license"/>
      <channelRef ref="channel-0"/>
      <archives>
        <archive><!--Built on: Wed Nov  8 11:07:05 2017.-->
          <complete>
            <size>34908058</size>
            <checksum>CHANGE_THIS_CHECKSUM</checksum>
            <url>YOUR_FILENAME_GOES_HERE.zip</url>
          </complete>
        </archive>
      </archives>
    </remotePackage>
  </addon:sdk-addon>
```

5. Now start XAMPP and run apache. Make sure you have set the directories correctly. Your directory must have the XML file
6. Put the URL, probably something like `localhost:8000/<YOUR_XML_FILENAME>.xml`, of this file after clicking the **+** sign

I used this quite a while ago.

**EDIT**: I re-read your question and I didn't see **very necessay** part. By that I am ***guessing*** it is one of the ***Android SDK Tool***. In your case your `****Put*fully*qualified*name*here****` **might** be "Android SDK Tools".

Also, the XML I wrote was for [add-on SDKs](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml). By the nature of your question you should edit the XML using [essential SDK XML](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml)

I found a similar [SOF QnA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install?rq=1) which you can look into

Comment: what is "Put fully qualified name"?

Comment: @Nofalnss I have edited my answer please see the edit. Also, did you try *Path 1-*?

Comment: Yes, path 1 not worked. after many failed downloads, sdk manager won't open from SDK folder, but still workin from android studio sdk manager

Comment: The "emulator" folder is empty and no package installed for it, so I'm trying to download emulator manually

Comment: So did you somehow install SDK?

Comment: Yes I do, it takes many fails, many tries, and many days, caues the package is so big, but finally it ended successfully. Thanks a lot for your corporation @chinmish